# Variable accessible outside the function

Tags: reactjs, function, variables, native

I have this React Native code and I want to use the gameOfTheUser variable (which is created in the arrow function: `userRef. ounce (' value'). then (snapshot =>`)outside this one. How to do it?

```
export default class RouterScreen extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
fb.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    // user exist
    var userRef = fb.database().ref('users/' + user.uid);
    userRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
      var gameOfTheUser = snapshot.child('game').val();
      console.log('0 : ' + gameOfTheUser);
    });
    if (gameOfTheUser !== null) {
      // gameOfTheUser --> error variable is not created
      // user in game --> redirect to Game (@user, @game)
      console.log('InGame');
      var gameID = gameOfTheUser;
      console.log('1 : ' + gameOfTheUser);
      console.log('1 : ' + gameID);
      navigate('Game', { user, gameID });
    } else {
      // user not in game --> redirect vers Choose (@user)
      console.log('NotInGame');
      navigate('Choose', { user });
    }
  } else {
    // user doesn't exist
    navigate('Auth');
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could :
1) update a var which isn't in this scope but in the global scope (using events for example)
2) set a state/props (depend if it change or not) and share it with a main component

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response! I'd love to test your first solution, but I don't really understand: can you give me an example code or a website or could I find out more? Thank you so much!